# signing applications release mode or dubug mode

Tags: android

I am working on the In-App tutorial and I am getting an error saying the version is not configured for billing through Google store.

There may be some confusion as to the version being used on my device.

This is my normal process
I have a signed key that has been setup and does work properly

I use Eclipse and I build my app there I build it constantly buy clicking the build icon and if my device is connected it opens on the device I do not sign anything that I know of (which leads to some confusion)

When I want to release the App I export it with the signed key and I have to export signed Application Package in the Android Tools I see when I right click on the App. An .apk file is generated and I upload that to google and everything works.

My question is when I simply run the App on my phone and it comes directly from eclipse what mode is it in

The In-App tutorial says I must be running the signed version on my phone.
Am I doing this automatically when I start it from Eclipse or is it in debug mode.
If it is debug mode how do I make it go into signed mode from Eclipse.

The version I need to upload to google is signed but is set as UNPUBLISHED as stated by the guide in the tutorial so I can not get it from the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test anything that has to interact with the Google store, you need to use the release version of the .apk file. Export it as usual from Eclipse, then use the command line tool to install the release .apk on the device or emulator:

```
>adb install myApp.apk
```

If you previously ran on the same device or emulator from within Eclipse, the app will have been signed with the debug cert and you will have to completely uninstall it first. Even the `-r` switch on the `apk install` command won't install if the signing certs are different.

Comment: I do not have apk on my system so I had to use the adb install syntax to get it installed I guess that eclipse puts a debug version on the device. Anyway I thank you a lot

Comment: @JeffJanes - When you export the signed version from Eclipse, if it isn't on your system, where is it? If you can upload it to Google Play, you should be able to install it on your device with `adb`. **OOPS**: The command is `adb`, not `apk`. I just fixed the answer.